# Running a function in separate task vs creating task and waiting to finish

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

Here is the situation:
I have to call a function in a separate thread

```
List<Task> TaskList = new List<Task>();

var LastTask = new Task(() => DoSomeMagic() <- warning is given here, not on the whole line);
LastTask.Start();
TaskList.Add(LastTask);

Task.WaitAll(TaskList.ToArray());
```

vs

```
Task.Run(() => DoSomeMagic());
```

In the first case I'm getting the warning: **Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the await operator to the result of the call.** and since I have await inside the DoSomeMagic function it does not awaits and the code of the main thread continues.

In the second situation everything works good.

The function is async itself:

```
private async Task DoSomeMagic()
{
    //Some code
    await OtherFunction(); //When this line starts executing the main thread continues
    //Some code
}
```

How do I make the first case to work? Because I have multiple tasks and I need to wait them all to finish first and after that the main thread should continue.

The problem I'm having is that when the execution comes to a line that has await in DoSomeMagic function then the main thread continues.

The second scenario I've just posted it to say that it's working but I can't use it as I need to run multiple threads in parallel. Not one by one.

Comment: you can try: `await Task.Run(() => DoSomeMagic(localTokens, servers, proxy));`

Comment: `await JoinTokensOldWay();` I probably does't understand the exact question..

Comment: `await Task.WhenAll(TaskList.ToArray());` - do you get the part where you await a task when you've reached the point in the code where you cannot proceed any further unless you know the answer? And that you don't just await at the lowest level and you're done - it's all the way up?

Comment: You should never use the `Task` constructor.

Comment: In which line are you getting the `Because this call is not awaited...` warning?

Comment: I've edited the question, I need the first scenario to work as I need to execute multiple threads in parallel and wait for them to finish before continuing with the main thread.

Comment: So you think that this line: `var LastTask = Task.Run(() => DoSomeMagic());` will force you to run only one task at a time? Have you tried it out and confirmed that the reality matches your expectations?

Comment: No it runs multiple, but it acts like it's not awaited. And when in the DoSomeMagic function i get to the line where I use await for some other func then thr main thread continues... and I want it to wait until the whole code is executed inside DoSomeMagic()

Comment: Stefan if I tell you how to solve the `Because this call is not awaited...` warning, you'll just end up with a more complicated version of the `Task.Run`. Using the `Task` constructor makes sense when you want to `Start` the `Task` at a later point. In your example the `Task` is `Start`ed immediately after it is created, so what's the point? I am also having trouble to understand what exactly is the problem with the `Task.Run`, and your latest comment didn't help much. I would suggest to focus on clarifying this problem inside the question, showing an example of actual and desirable behavior.